# Sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID

Tags: php, cron, sendmail, phpmailer

This one just suddenly appeared.

I've noticed I wasn't receiving some email from a cron script.

I gave output to the cron by removing the 2> /dev/null and saw this:

**sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID. Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?
sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID. Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?**

It seems is being triggered from a call to PHPMailer::send()

I run the chown root:mailtrap /usr/sbin/sendmail solution etc ... with no luck. The error still persists.

Something to notice is that the MTA we use in our server is Exim4.

Any idea and help is appreciated.

Comment: vps? localhost? sharedhost?

Comment: It's a VPS. This suddenly appeared. As a comment we had a new PHP build to 5.4 a few weeks ago.

Comment: this is not a regular forum sites, questions are answered within minutes of being posted, my comment came 4 minutes after the post, so being weeks latter, i have moved on.

Comment: Honestly didn't see your comment 4 mins after my post. Also didn't get notified.